# Controlled impedance and differential pairs over M.2 edge connector

Tags: impedance, layout, high-speed

I have a System On Module I'm designing that I'd like to fit inside the M.2 form factor. My issue is the dozen or so high speed traces that need to run over the edge connector to my M.2 connector. The [connector from TE](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-2199230-4.html) I'm considering doesn't provide impedance test results, though most documentation states it'd be the same as PCIE (~85 Ω). Assuming I have 4 90 Ω traces for USB and 8 100 Ω traces for my ethernet MDIO interface - how do I handle these over a card edge connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference in impedance is sufficiently small (15% isn't bad for digital) and sufficiently short (USB 2.0 needs ~240MHz of bandwidth while ethernet needs a bit less).

Generally in the RF world you can get away with discontinuities less than 1/10th of your wavelength of interest (in this case 240MHz, make it 1GHz to include the third harmonic and some extra margin).

A 1 GHz signal has a wavelength of ~30cm in air or around 20cm on a pcb (higher dielectric constants shorten things). So that's still 2cm if we go by the 1/10th rule of thumb. I'd imagine the m.2 interface would add less than 1cm so I think you're pretty right here either way.

We can even calculate the reflection co-efficient if you want to be doubly sure. It's just (Zl-Z0)/(Zl+Z0), which'd only be ~0.08 when transitioning from a 100ohm trace to an 85ohm one, consequently this corresponds to a VWSR of ~1.2 (which is more or less on par with more than a few cheap RF connectors) and means that your return loss is ~20dB (so about 1/100th of the signal power gets reflected). For digital signals (especially sub-Gbit ones), that sounds alright to me.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized my tolerances would be anywhere near that wide.

Comment: @maxmclau controlled impedance doesn't start to be a serious issue until either your signals travel distances equivalent to your wavelengths which is around 200MHz/meter over FR4 or coax (but you start seeing effects at ~1/10th of that) or until you move into the GHz realm or both, *especially both*.

Comment: The quarter-wave transformer will produce extremely high voltages on the unloaded end. I expect this effect, where energy is stored at the interface's various resonant modes, to be a dominate cause of InterSymbolInterference.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to [this](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-767055-5.html) the SMD version is 50 Ω  maybe close enough, (for gov't work;)  The other version is not specified and likely to be more reactive.